# Can I switch alt and super modifiers in Sublime Text on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, sublimetext2

I want to use the exact same keyboard shortcuts in Sublime Text 2 in both Mac OS X and Windows, but there are two things standing in the way:

1. ST2 respects the conventions of the OS it's running on, so that (e.g.) Find is `control-F` on Windows but `super-F` (aka `command-F`) on Mac OS X. Can I tell ST2 to use `control` under Mac OS X instead of `super` for these things?
2. The Mac keyboard puts `super`/`command` where a PC keyboard has `alt`/`option`. Can I also tell ST2 to read `command` as `alt` and `option` as `super`?

I am used to Emacs, where (1) isn't a problem because the keyboard shortcuts are already the same, and (2) can be mitigated with this in the Emacs configuration:

```
(setq mac-option-modifier 'alt
      mac-command-modifier 'meta
      mac-allow-anti-aliasing nil)
```

Under ST2, I can mostly sidestep (1) with [sublemacspro](https://github.com/grundprinzip/sublemacspro); it's not totally perfect but I think it could be good enough. I haven't been able to find any way to accomplish (2) though.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried those key bindings [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html), in the Sublime Text documentation ?

Comment: AFAICT, that page is about assigning keys to commands; I want to assign a key to another key. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Ok, but you can't bind, for example, `option` to `super`, these are system bindings for ST. The only way you could try to do that, is to bind `option` as to replace `super` in the default bindings. Instead of, for example, `super+T`, make the same behavior bind to `option+T`.

Comment: I see. I was afraid of that. I was hoping I could do this automatically somehow, or that I could find a .sublime-keymap file that shipped with ST which might at least list all of the ones I would need. Thank you for your help though.